# Read compressed stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, unix, gzip

I would like to have such call:

```
pv -ptebar compressed.csv.gz | python my_script.py
```

Inside `my_script.py` I would like to decompress `compressed.csv.gz` and parse it using Python csv parser. I would expect something like this:

```
import csv
import gzip
import sys


with gzip.open(fileobj=sys.stdin, mode='rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print(next(reader))
    print(next(reader))
    print(next(reader))
```

Of course it doesn't work because `gzip.open` doesn't have `fileobj` argument. Could you provide some working example solving this issue?

**UPDATE**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(next(reader))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 287, in read1
    return self._buffer.read1(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 461, in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 404, in _read_gzip_header
    magic = self._fp.read(2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 91, in read
    self.file.read(size-self._length+read)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

The traceback above appeared after applying @Rawing advice.

Comment: Did you try to just dump some `f.readline()` results to see what does your unpacked stream look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gzip.open(sys.stdin.buffer, 'rt')` fixes issue for Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

In python 3.3+, you can pass a file object to [`gzip.open`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/gzip.html#gzip.open):

> The filename argument can be an actual filename (a str or bytes object), or an existing file object to read from or write to.

So your code should work if you just omit the `fileobj=`:

```
with gzip.open(sys.stdin, mode='rt') as f:
```

Or, a slightly more efficient solution:

```
with gzip.open(sys.stdin.buffer, mode='rb') as f:
```

---

If for some odd reason you're using a python older than 3.3, you can directly invoke the [`gzip.GzipFile` constructor](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile). However, these old versions of the `gzip` module didn't have support for files opened in text mode, so we'll use `sys.stdin`'s underlying buffer instead:

```
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=sys.stdin.buffer) as f:
```

Comment: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found` raised. It doesn't amaze me while stdin is already open.

Comment: Ok, I tried `gzip.open` with Python 3 and it actually changed an error. Currently I have a problem involving encoding: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`. Can you still help?

Comment: I just experimented and replacing `sys.stdin` with `sys.stdin.buffer` for Python 3 has fixed an issue. Could you update your answer? Then I could accept your solution.

Comment: tbh none of listed examples work for me currently. `sys.stdin` fails with encoding issue, `sys.stdin.buffer, mode='rb'` fails with csv error, and opening with `GzipFile` under Python 2.7 fails with error of missing `buffer` attribute of `file` type.

Comment: `with gzip.open(sys.stdin.buffer, 'rt') as f:` is working solution under Python 3. Could you update your answer with THIS statement, please? Working solution for Python 2.7 is also welcome.

Comment: @pt12lol I'm not really comfortable with adding that code to my answer, because it doesn't make any sense for that to work. I might be wrong, but to me it seems like that code works only because of pure luck. I'll accept the lack of a green tick next to my answer for now.